# Laravel use sum with multy join query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

guys i try to get data from mysql with join query but i need to SUM my rate column, after i try to execute query i get a error.

My query is this :

```
 $data['companies'] = db::table('companies')
    ->leftjoin('company_rate', 'companies.id', '=', 'company_rate.company_id')
    ->select('companies.*', DB::raw('SUM(company_rate.rate) as company_rates'))
    ->groupBy('companies.id', 'company_rate.rate') 
    ->get();
    return view('allcompanies', $data);
```

Error code is this :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'expresslog.companies.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `companies`.*, SUM(company_rate.rate) as company_rates from `companies` left join `company_rate` on `companies`.`id` = `company_rate`.`company_id` group by `companies`.`id`, `company_rate`.`rate`)
```

Comment: use for all columns taha are not in the GROUP BY aggregation functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve this by using a join sub to get the sum rates

```
$subQuery = DB::table('company_rate')
    ->select('company_id')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(company_rate.rate) AS company_rates')
    ->groupBy('company_id');

$data['companies'] = DB::table('companies')
    ->joinSub($subQuery, 'sum_rates',function ($join) {
        $join->on('companies.id', '=', 'sum_rates.user_id');
    })->get();
```

Comment: Yes, but i want to select all columns from companies table if i want to select all table maybe i need to group all one by one ?

Comment: I updated my solution, let me know if that's what you meant @user6358067

Comment: Everything is ok , thank you for the support guys :)

Answer (score 0):

This code is work fine now :)

```
$data['companies'] = db::table('companies')
            ->leftjoin('company_rate', 'companies.id', '=', 'company_rate.company_id')
            ->select('companies.id', 'companies.company_name', 'companies.company_mol', 'companies.company_eik', 'companies.company_dds_number', 'companies.company_phone', 'companies.company_email', 'companies.company_adress', 'companies.company_agent_phone', 'companies.company_agent_email', DB::raw('SUM(company_rate.rate) as company_rates'))
            ->groupBy('companies.id', 'companies.company_name', 'companies.company_mol', 'companies.company_eik', 'companies.company_dds_number', 'companies.company_phone', 'companies.company_email', 'companies.company_adress', 'companies.company_agent_phone', 'companies.company_agent_email') 
            ->get();
```

Comment: It's decidedly odd to sum the thing your grouping by